# ISIN() not working for List - Pandas Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, function, isin

I have a dataframe with product name and volumes. I also have two variables with per unit cost.
LVP_Cost=xxxx

HVP_Cost=xxxx

However, I would like to apply the per unit cost only to selected product types. To achive this I am using `isin()` within a user defined function.

I am getting and error message:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isin'

Here is my code;

```py
LVP_list=['BACS','FP','SEPA']
HVP_list=['HVP','CLS']

def calclate_cost (row):  
    
    if row['prod_final'].isin(LVP_list):
        return row['volume']*LVP_per_unit_cost
    
    elif row['prod_final']==(HVP_list): 
        return row['volume']*HVP_per_unit_cost
    else:
        return 0


mguk['cost_usd']=mguk.apply(calclate_cost,axis=1)
```

Please could you help

Answer (score 1):

`row['prod_final']` is a string containing the value of that column in the current row, not a Pandas series. So use the regular `in` operator.

```
if row['prod_final'] in LVP_list:
```